# How to handle 307 http request redirect in angularJS1 or JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way I can handle http request 307 redirect in angularJS 1 or JS ? We are trying to integrate Nest with our app, for the same we need to call a Nest API which returns 307 redirect URL, details can be found in below link

https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/how-to-handle-redirects

It seems to be working fine as it is for android but on iOS app, it does not work as expected. I believe its not forwarding the Authorization token for 2nd request. If we use redirected URL in our request then it seems to be working fine but problem is the redirect URL keeps changing. Would appreciate if someone can help us here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got this working using below cordova plugin.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-http

It allows me to disable redirect. I'm able to get hold of redirect URL and make another call with appropriate headers. It solves my issue, not sure if there is any other better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a custom Http interceptor and handle all of the requests/responses as per your wish. Here is a simple implementation of HttpInterceptor service.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
app.factory('HttpInterceptor', HttpInterceptor);

HttpInterceptor.$inject = [
    '$q'
];

function HttpInterceptor($q) {
    return {

        'request': function (config) {
            //do magic here
        },

        'requestError': function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 307) {
                //do magic here
            }

            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },

        'response': function (response) {
            //do magic here
        },

        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 307) {
                //do magic here
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
};
})();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @ved0 for your response. But unfortunately interceptors not helping here. It only catches response from redirected URL i.e. from the second request. My objective is to catch response from the original request before it gets redirected. Any other suggestion would be appreciated.